# OS installation from usb doesn't start

Tags: boot, bios

I want to upgrade my laptop (HP Pavillion dv6002er). So, i installed SSD disk, more RAM and want to install OS.

It didn't work. So, i returned the hardware configuration to factory default.

I have factory Win 7 installed. Also Ubuntu 20 are installed. It work both.

When i try to install OS from the usb, OS logo screen appeared and nothing happens...

Try different usb drives, different OS(Ubuntu, Manjaro, Win 7, XP). It's all the same result.

The boot usb works on the other computer.

Only win xp gives some kind of info: "...recent hardware or software change might be the cause... windows\system32\boot\winload.exe... status: 0xc0000001".

Can anybody help?

Some specs:

Processor Information:

Version: AMD Phenom(tm) II P960 Quad-Core Processor

External Clock: 200 MHz
Max Speed: 1800 MHz
Current Speed: 1800 MHz

Core Count: 4
Core Enabled: 4
Thread Count: 4
Characteristics: 64-bit capable

Guys, don't have any suggestions?

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: How did you prepare the USB?  Some methods only make UEFI install media, and your machine needs legacy.